# How to Retrieve Firestore document data through Angular Application?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Here I need to retrieve the documents data and document id to show the relevant post data. But I didn't find any better way to do it. Please help me.

```
public postId: string;
public posts: any = [];    

this.postService.getRecentFivePosts().subscribe((res1) => {
                console.log(res1);
            });

getRecentFivePosts() {
        return this.firestore.collection('Post', ref => ref.orderBy('date', 'desc').limit(5)).snapshotChanges();
    }
```

Comment: "I didn't find a better way" What is wrong with the code you currently have?

Comment: I don't know how to get the document data and id from the res1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the payload property in the Firestore document to get the data and use the doc.id property for the document id. Change the following code according to your requirement.

Refer - https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md

```
this.postService.getRecentFivePosts().subscribe((res1) => {
                res1.map((k) => {
                    this.posts.push({
                        post: k.payload.doc.data(),
                        id: k.payload.doc.id
                    });
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, this code worked for me, I'll change it to my preferred way.